# Elli with Elixir Basic usage issue

Tags: elixir

I am using elli https://github.com/knutin/elli in my Elixir application.

The sample code is provided below. It is quite basic, every time it is run, I only get "Internal Server Error". I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can any one please help ?

```
defmodule Client.TestHttp do
  @behaviour :elli_handler

  def handle(_Req,_Args) do
    handle(:elli_request.method(Req), :elli_request.path(Req),Args)
  end

  def handle_event(_,_,_)do
    :ok
  end

  def handle(:GET,[],_)do
    {:ok, [], "OkGet"}
  end
end
```

This is how I am executing

```
{:ok,pid}=:elli.start_link [callback: Client.TestHttp, port: 2020]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you haven't fully translated the Erlang code from the example and are still using variables that begin with an uppercase letter.

Change handle to:

```
  def handle(req, args) do
    handle(:elli_request.method(req), :elli_request.path(req), args)
  end
```

Notice the difference in the variable names. In Elixir, variables are written in `snake_case` and modules in `CamelCase`. Using and underscore (`_`) such as `_var` in a match indicates that the variable is unused.

Your code would actually be expanding `Req` and `Args` to atoms due to module names in Elixir being atoms:

```
Req == :'Elixir.Req' # true
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers above, I would like to write up a complete guide on getting `knutin/elli` to work with Elixir.
The above answers are correct, but I needed some more information to get up and running in my new elixir project.

1. Implement a handler that has `@behaviour :elli_handler`

   This is your router/controller. A bare minimum example version of this looks like this:

   ```
   # lib/elli_handler.ex
   defmodule ElliHandler do
     @behaviour :elli_handler
     alias :elli_request, as: Request

     def handle(req, args) do
       handle(Request.method(req), Request.path(req), req, args)
     end

     def handle(:GET, _, req, args) do
       # do something with the request.
       # e.g. you can use Request.get_arg/2 to fetch a query param
       say = Request.get_arg("say", req)
       # Return a tuple with 3 elements
       # status code, list of header tuples, response body
       {200, [], "echo, #{say}"}
     end

     # Here you can react to all kinds of events of the full connection/request/response cycle
     # You must implement this, otherwise elli wont function properly, as it evaluates
     # the return value of handle_event/3.
     def handle_event(event, args, config) do
       # Here would be a good point to handle logging.
       # IO.inspect([event, args, config])
       :ok
     end

   end
   ```
2. Lets use an app that starts an elli supervisor

   ```
   # lib/elli_supervisor.ex
   defmodule ElliSupervisor do
     use Supervisor

     def start_link(ref, options) do
       Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, options, name: ref)
     end

     def init(options) do
       children = [
         worker(:elli, [options], id: :elli_http_server)
       ]
       supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
     end

     def shutdown(ref) do
       case Supervisor.terminate_child(ref, :elli_http_server) do
         :ok -> Supervisor.delete_child(ref, :elli_http_server)
         err -> err
       end
     end
   end

   # lib/app.ex
   defmodule App do
     use Application

     def start(_type, _args) do
       import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false
       # lets start our elli supervisor, setting its options
       # callback should be set to the elli handler that implements the elli_handler behaviour
       # port will be the port elli is listening on, defaults to 8080
       ElliSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, callback: ElliHandler, port: 3000)
     end

   end

   # in mix.exs
   def application do
     [
       mod: {App, []}
     ]
   end
   ```
3. Add elli as a dependency to your mix.exs

   Run `mix get.deps` to install your dependencies.
   Start your server with `mix run --no-halt` or in a console using `iex -S mix`.

   ```
   # in mix.exs
   defp deps do
     [
       # elli is our web server layer
       {:elli, github: "knutin/elli"}
     ]
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Gazier's answer (which is correct, of course), your code also looks wrong in another way. In your original source you've got:

```
def handle(_Req,_Args) do
    handle(:elli_request.method(Req), :elli_request.path(Req),Args)
end
```

The parameter to the call to `:elli_request.method` would need to be `_Req` and the parameters to the `:elli_request.path` would also need to be `_Req` and `_Args`. If variables starting with an uppercase letter were correct (they're not) it would look like this:

```
 def handle(_Req,_Args) do
        handle(:elli_request.method(_Req), :elli_request.path(_Req),_Args)
    end
```

But as Gazier pointed out your variables are not correctly cased anyway.